# codeigniter rest api not working on liver server

Tags: codeigniter

I have a url:-

http://brokers4homes.esoftech.in/

I have created a web service and created a customer
`$route['api/v1_0/usersignup'] = "api/user_api/usersignup"`

I am hitting url:-

```
http://brokers4homes.esoftech.in/index.php?api/v1_0/usersignup
```

but it does not give me any json result instead it redirects me to home mage:-

This is my form:-

```
http://brokers4homes.esoftech.in/index.php/rest_server
```

Comment: Can you share the htaccess and the full route file and the code in the usersignup function?

Comment: use fiddle or demo page, we want to see more code.